# header for loop same as body duplicate code

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, iteration

I'm trying to output a 2D table to a file, including a header row and column.  I would rather not check in the loop if it's the header file, as it is distracting for the reader; but I would rather not write the inner for loop twice because I fear it may accidentally diverge in maintenance.  Both loops are spanning a range in double, but I use an integer in parallel to avoid round off problems at the loop end.

Below is the code with the 'header row condition' `i<0` in the for loop.

```
Xi = range.Xi.min();
for(int i = -1; i< 128; i++, Xi += range.Xi/128) {
    if(i<0)                                         
        File.write( format_blank, strlen(format_blank) );       // write top corner of table
    else                                    
        write( File, format_nth_csv, Xi );                      // write the 1st column

    dXi = range.dXi.min();
    for(int j=0; j < 64; j++, dXi += range.dXi/64) {
        if (i<0)                                
            write( File, format_1st_csv, dXi);                  // write the header row
        else                                            
            write( File, format_nth_csv, kernelDensity.evaluatedAt( Xi, dXi ) );// write the table contents
    }
}
```

1. Is the compiler smart enough to unwrap the header pass at the loop?
2. Is readable? or would it be better separated into a header loop and a body loop?

Comment: I would write the header loop separately.  It's much easier to read your code if you do this, and because of that it's actually less prone to mistakes than trying to roll it into one.

Comment: Even if the compiler didn't loop unroll, the branch predictor would have nearly perfect prediction anyway, so it really doesn't matter.  I'd go with what paddy said though.